# Form validations - Applied globally (Inconsistent behaviour)

Tags: angular

I have a working scenario of form validation as below:

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 ">                        
                  <div class="form-group" formGroupName="rptrfirstName" >
                      <span>First Name / Given Name </span>
                      <div class="input-group" >                            
                      <input type="text" class="form-control " [(ngModel)]="reporterFName" formControlName="reporterFName"> 
                      <select class="form-control col-sm-3" style="padding-right: 2px;padding-right: 2px;"  [(ngModel)]="reporterFNameNV" formControlName="reporterFNameNV">     
                          <option [ngValue]="null">Select</option>
                         <option *ngFor="let fNameNv of fNameNvs" [value]="fNameNv.CODE"  >{{ fNameNv.CODE}}</option>  
                        </select>                            
                  </div>
                  <small class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.controls.rptrfirstName.hasError('bothEmpty') && notSubmitted ">
                      Please enter information in one of the above fields.
                   </small>
                   <small class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.controls.rptrfirstName.hasError('bothCaptured') && notSubmitted ">
                    Information is expected in any one of the above fields.
                 </small>
               </div>
              </div>
```

I have validator applied on component :

```
 rptrfirstName: formBuilder.group({
                    reporterFName: new FormControl(''),
                    reporterFNameNV:new FormControl('')
                  }, {validator: [this.bothEmptyValidator, this.bothCapturedValidator]}) ,
```

Since I have above sort of scenario on many group controls on many components in the application , i have created below for global usage:

```
@Injectable()

export class FormErrors {

bothEmptyValidator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {
    const KeyArray= Object.keys(fg.controls) 
    const ValuesArray= Object.values(fg.controls) 
    let field1 = ValuesArray[0].value;
    let field2 = ValuesArray[1].value;         
    return !field1 && !field2 ? {bothEmpty: true} : null;
}

bothCapturedValidator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {    
    const KeyArray= Object.keys(fg.controls) 
    const ValuesArray= Object.values(fg.controls) 
    let field1 = ValuesArray[0].value;
    let field2 = ValuesArray[1].value;           
    return field1 && field2 ? {bothCaptured: true} : null;
}
getEmptyMessage() {
         return 'Please enter information in one of the above fields.';  
  }
getBothCapturedMessage() {
    return 'Information is expected in any one of the above fields.';  
}  
}.
```

I am injecting the above thru constructor of the component and modified HTML as below:

```
 <small class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.controls.rptrTitle.hasError('bothEmpty') && notSubmitted ">{{_fmError.getEmptyMessage()}}                    </small>
<small class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.controls.rptrTitle.hasError('bothCaptured') && notSubmitted ">{{_fmError.getBothCapturedMessage()}}
                      </small>
```

I have observed that the validations are working fine for the first time (with both empty and both captured conditions)..However when i try to play around with continuous changes in data input , validation mgs are thrown improperly... 
Have noted that validation messages are perfect and accurate if i handle validations at the component level with HTML part as mentioned in the initial block of this post.

I prefer to keep my code without redundancy, hence global validator.
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Post a complete minimal example, as a stackblitz, reproducing the issue.

Comment: Also, you’re mixing template based (ngModel) and reactive forms. That’s not a good idea.

Comment: @JB Nizet, @ MikeOne, There was some mistake in the HTML of the controls i was using for testing..Have corrected and it works fine...@ MikeOne, comment about ngModel usage , triggered a deeper understanding about how to implement reactive forms...Thank you.!